# Dynamically adding flags to a command

Tags: tcl

Is it possible to dynamically add flags to a command, without using `eval`?

For example, I wish to perform the following with a variable:

```
set isCaseSensitive 1
if {$isCaseSensitive == 1} {
    set res [regexp -nocase -- $regexp $str]
} else {
    set res [regexp -- $regexp $str]
}

# The following does NOT work

set regexp_flags ""
if {$isCaseSensitive == 1} {
    append regexp_flags " -nocase"
}
set res [regexp $regexp_flags -- $regexp $str]
```

Using Tcl 8.5

---

**Edit #1, 12:41 UTC:**
*(Response to the commenter Jerry)*

I've executed the code:

```
set regexp_flags ""
if {$isCaseSensitive == 1} {
    append regexp_flags "-nocase"
}

set res [regexp -line -all -inline -indices $regexp_flags -- $regexp $str]
```

And received the following error (omitted irrelevant text):

```
regexp match variables not allowed when using -inline
    while executing
"regexp -line -all -inline -indices $regexp_flags -- $regexp $str"
```

That happens because that Tcl thinks that `$str` is a 4th parameter, which is forbidden while using the `-inline` flag.

See [regexp command documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regexp.htm).

---

**Edit #2, 14:01 UTC:**

Apparently for some reason, the non-printable characters that are in my subject string (`$str`) have some negative effect on this command. *(Tcl isn't binary protected or something?)*
I've tried to delete those characters before trying to `regexp` and it now works as expected.

```
set regexp_flags ""
if {$isCaseSensitive == 1} {
    append regexp_flags "-nocase"
}

set str [regsub -all -- {[^[:print:]\t\n\r\f\v]} $str ""]
set res [regexp -line -all -inline -indices $regexp_flags -- $regexp $str]
```

Comment: Why not simply `append regexp_flags "-nocase"`? It's working on my Tcl8.5. (inserting the space made it no more work)

Comment: @Jerry: Plz see my first edit.

Comment: Variables refer to captured groups. I'm having no problem whatsoever... Here's a [demo](http://codepad.org/nuJgVnp4) and it's running fine on 8.4.

Comment: @Jerry I've found the reason to my problem. See my 2nd edit. Thx! :)

Comment: I just noticed your edit :) No problem!

Comment: Tcl _is entirely_ binary-safe, provided you read the data in with the correct encoding. Tcl defaults to reading as text (in your system's encoding for that purpose) as that's the most common case by far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 8.5 and 8.6, the best way to this sort of thing is:

```
set regexp_flags ""
if {$isCaseSensitive == 1} {
    lappend regexp_flags -nocase
}

set res [regexp -line -all -inline -indices {*}$regexp_flags -- $regexp $str]
```

---

In 8.4 (and before, in case you're *really* old school!) you needed this construction instead (and you *definitely* need the second `[list …]` because the RE and string are unlikely to be neat barewords):

```
set regexp_flags ""
if {$isCaseSensitive == 1} {
    lappend regexp_flags -nocase
}

set res [eval [list regexp -line -all -inline -indices] $regexp_flags [list -- $regexp $str]]
```

Though that is perhaps better written as:

```
set regexp_cmd [list regexp -line -all -inline -indices]
if {$isCaseSensitive == 1} {
    lappend regexp_cmd -nocase
}

set res [eval $regexp_cmd [list -- $regexp $str]]
```

Wouldn't you rather use 8.5? Or put `(?i)` at the front of the RE (which also makes it case-insensitive)?